# Map Method sql.row extraction - data type error in Spark

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I have a `.sql.Row` type `RDD`.

I am using the `map` method to unpack from the `row` and create a new `RDD`.

This question builds directly from what I learnt in [Scala RDD String manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971325/scala-rdd-string-manipulation/38972989#38972989).

In the original `RDD`, `vertices_raw` I have a field `Metrics` that I use map on.

```
val vertices = vertices_raw.rdd.map(row=> (row.getAs[String]("Metrics").map(_.stripPrefix("name").toLong))
```

Resulting in:

```
error: value stripPrefix is not a member of Char
```

The same goes for `.drop` method for removing `name`.

I have tried adding a `toString` in attempt to convert from `Char` to `String` with no change.

```
val vertices = vertices_raw.rdd.map(row=> (row.getAs[String]("Metrics").toString.map(_.stripPrefix("name").toLong))
```

Instead of `getAs[String]` I also tried `getString`.

```
val vertices = vertices_raw.rdd.map(row=> (row.getString("Metrics").map(_.stripPrefix("name").toLong))
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("toid")
 required: Int
```

My practical question is how do I convert from `Char` to `String`? before performing the `map` function?

My fundamental question is what exactly does `getAs[String]` mean if it doesn't literally mean get and in String format? I have a misunderstood this clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a map on a string - that is going to map over each char of the string.  If you just want to call stripPrefix then just do that without the map.

```
row.getAs[String]("Metrics").stripPrefix("name").toLong
```